# Why doesn't Traktor update the key and BPM fields after I analyze the track?

Tags: software, dj, mixing, traktor

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yul-BedR-VY) shows the issue. After restarting the computer and Traktor everything worked fine, but I wonder what could have caused the issue. The track in question was not being used/opened by other programs.

Comment: ask the developers who wrote the software...

Comment: Ok, that's strange. No BPM and no BeatGrid. If you set the BeatGrid manually does it work then? Another thing comes into mind is the file write protected?

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that's a bug, and one that NI fixed a while ago. I haven't had that issue in years

Your version of Traktor is 6 years old. Traktor 3, a major version upgrade, was released in 2018. I would recommend upgrading--3 is a huge improvement

I wouldn't even want to file a bug report on it because that's just less developer time that can be spent on making cool new stuff, if they even support that anymore

And if you must stay on 2, do a minor version update. I was on 2.6.8 for a long time, not sure if that's the latest minor release of 2 but I can vouch for it being solid